# SQL Loader issue loading decimal negative numbers

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

I have the following issue using SQL Loader to load a small table, my process populates a field which can be populated for possitive or negative decimal numbers, and the problem is that when the number is possitive, the process rounds with 2 positions, but if it's negative only use 1 position. I need 2 position, and this is the simple code:

```
UNRECOVERABLE LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE [SCHEMA].TABLE1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
FIELD1 "trim(:FIELD1 )" 
)
```

Example:

```
Source:  12345,78 Target:  1234,78

Source: -12345,78 Target: -1234,8
```

Edit1: It just happend with number with 7 or more integer length (X < -1000000), but I can insert this numbers with regular insert instead of SQLLoader.

Edit2: I have noticed that it is not a problem with sql*loader because the .ctl is already wrong. This file is generated with python and SQL with this properties:

```
set colsep |
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 10000
set termout off
set feedback off
set arraysize 250
```

But I dont know where it is defined the lenght of each field, and this looks the error.

Comment: Have you tried using ROUND(:FIELD1,2) ?

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the table?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. I have noticed that there are some negative numbers with more than one position decimal but never when the integer part has 7 or more lenght. But I have tried to insert manually a number with no sql loader and it works perfectly.

Comment: Data type is NUMBER

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're not looking correctly. Data is, probably, stored OK, but you don't see it. Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test (field1 number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Control file:

```
load data
infile *
replace into table test
fields terminated by '|' trailing nullcols
(
field1
)
begindata
12345,78
-12345,78
987654321
-987654321
987654321,01234
-987654321,01234
111333444,887766
-112333444,887766
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test26.ctl log=test26.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto Kol 21 08:52:10 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7
Commit point reached - logical record count 8

SQL> select * from test;

    FIELD1
----------
  12345,78
 -12345,78
 987654321
-987654321
 987654321
-987654321
 111333445
-112333445

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Ooops! Seems to be wrong, eh? But, if you fix the column format ...

```
SQL> col field1 format 999g999g999g990d000000
SQL> select * from test;

                 FIELD1
-----------------------
          12.345,780000
         -12.345,780000
     987.654.321,000000
    -987.654.321,000000
     987.654.321,012340
    -987.654.321,012340
     111.333.444,887766
    -112.333.444,887766

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

See? Everything is here.

I guess that, if you used a GUI, you wouldn't have such problems. The former sentence doesn't mean that you should NOT use SQL*Plus - on the contrary; just ... learn how to use it properly :)

**[EDIT, after reading the comment]**

It is `SET NUMFORMAT` you might be looking for:

```
SQL> select -12334.789123 from dual;

-12334.789123
-------------
   -12334,789

SQL> set numformat 999g999g990d000000
SQL> select -12334.789123 from dual;

      -12334.789123
-------------------
     -12.334,789123

SQL>
```

Comment: I think you are really close, but I dont know... I have added a edit2 in the post.

Comment: `SET NUMFORMAT`, probably. I edited my message and added an example, have a look.